# Adding styles to iOS project - Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, styling

I've just started with iOS development using swift and I would like to know if I can create styles and themes as we do in Android projects.

Do I really have to set the background, fonts and colors for every ViewController?

This is the closest I could get: http://sdbr.net/post/Themes-in-Swift/

Answer (score 1):

I am a newbie as well, but in experience the closest design you could do is yes design every UIViewController in the storyboard. Actually I think you could make a whole class for the theme and style but that requires a lot of coding, so I suggest you do the designs in the storyboard for now.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS there are no style or theme like in Android, but You can use some shared class to customize some common UI components for the whole Application. For example you can customize Navigation bar or Tabbar once using global static class and method like

```
UINavigationBar.appereance()
UITabBarItem.appearance()
```

...

Answer (score -3):

Enter Xcode, left corner 
Xcode->preference ->Fonts&color ..Have fun~